# HTML5 / Javascript - Making preloaded Images DOM Accesible?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, preload, preloader

I'm trying to bridge the gap between loading/preloading images and other items in a manifest and making them accessible to CSS and JS in conventional `DIV` tags.

I understand the preloading process. I then have an array of images or objects, etc, that are viewable in a window/stage object, but I want them in `DIV` tags to reference them.

How do people go about loading/preloading images and then reference them in a standard HTML5 markup page?

Like, imagine I have a site with clean markup and scripts/styles links. Now I want to preload it. I can't find any documentation that makes that clear.

Does anybody know what I mean or can point out the perspective of trying to load a page of content and then access it with `getElementById`?

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Comment: just use the same urls in the manifest as you do in html/css

Comment: So you want to load couple of images and then access it on demand??

Answer (score 0):

Preloading images is not directly related to being able to access elements in DOM.

Preloading tells the browser to download a web resource in advance already when the browser would otherwise not download it yet.

The ability to access an element in DOM on the other hand depends on the stage of downloading the page itself.